# BaseGameActivity.runOnUpdateThread() vs. Entity.registerUpdateHandler()

Tags: android, andengine

Is there any difference if I execute a `Runnable` with `runOnUpdateThread()` or I register an update handler into an Entity and execute the code with that?

I would like to remove a `Sprite` from the Scene with `Sprite.detachSelf()`. In this case the tutorial says that this method must be invoked in the Update Thread with `BaseGameActivity.runOnUpdateThread()`. But with this solution I have to pass the activity object to every object that want to use the `runOnUpdateThread()`. Well... I do not like it.

My question is if I create a `RunnableHandler` object in an Entity and register it with `registerUpdateHandler()` and new Runnable is added to `RunnableHandler`, is this solution identical with the `runOnUpdateThread()` functionality. Is this `Runnable` executed in Update Thread?

```
/* MySprite is attached to a Scene object */
public class MySprite extends Sprite {
   private final RunnableHandler UPDATE_HANDLER = new RunnableHandler();

   public MySprite() {
       registerUpdateHandler(UPDATE_HANDLER);
   }

   /* called when the sprite has to be removed from scene */
   public void removeMyself() {
       Runnable r = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               detachSelf();
           }
       };
       UPDATE_HANDLER.postRunnable(r);
   }
}
```

I am asking this because with the standard solution everything is working fine. But with the update handler solution I got this exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 19, size is 19
>     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:1402)
>     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:284)
>     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:1167)
>     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateScene(Engine.java:591)
>     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:586)
>     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
>     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)

It usually comes when attach/detach functions called **not** in Update Thread. Am I right?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why don't you create the detach logic inside the scene that will contain those sprites? Your scene could extend from a BaseScene which contains a reference for the Activity or if you don't want that BaseScene approach you could also create a WeekReference of your Activity inside that scene. Would any of these approaches help you achieve your goals?

Comment: Hi GuilhE, of course I was able to solve the problem with other way. But my question was totally different. I do not understand why I got the above exception when I used the delineated code. Is the registered update handler code really invoked in update thread as I expected or not? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code in [Entity](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/Entity.java#L1400) a theory what happens is:

1. The line shown, picks up a entity count = 19 (from log)
2. one of the the entity.get(i).onUpdate() calls removeMyself()
3. The runnable for detachSelf is queued.
4. On the next entity.get(i).onUpdate() will result in the UpdateHandler to be run via [onUpdate](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/Entity.java#L1165) (updatehandlers are run in onManagedUpdate)
5. the [detachSelf](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/Entity.java#L705) removes the child from the parent list (the caller) (where entry count still 19 but the length of mChildren/entities is now 18)

Just a theory from looking at code... I think a good point to start to get the answer is to look at the loop in [Entity](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/entity/Entity.java#L1400) and see if 'entities' is modified during the loop. (Note: the 'final entities' just prevents reassigning variable, not modifying the list)